# Comparing a textbox input to a sql query

Tags: c#, sql, database

Here is my code in c#, it is saying "No data exists for the row/column.", how can I improve this code to make it work properly?

```
db = new OleDbConnection();
db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + fileName;
db.Open();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM GroupNameNS WHERE GroupName = '" + Groupnametxt.Text.Trim() + "'";

cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (Groupnametxt.Text.Trim() == (string)rdr["GroupName"])
{
  MessageBox.Show("Group Name taken, please try another name", "Error in Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
  membernumber1.ReadOnly = true;
}
else
{
  sql = "INSERT INTO GroupNameNS VALUES ('" + Groupnametxt.Text.Trim() + "')";
  membernumber1.ReadOnly = false;
  cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db);
  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: "...or something like that"?  Give us the exact error if you want help...  Are you querying a Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: "Or something like that"? If you want people to help you with an error, please at least take the time to document the exact error message. Also, it would probably be a good idea for you to google 'sql injection attack'.

Comment: Please provide more information. "Or something like that" doesn't help us deduce the problem. Do you have a stack trace? Your above code is highly SQL injectable at the moment also. You should consider using SqlParameters for your queries. You shouldn't need to check if Groupnametxt is equal to what your DataReader contains, because the query has already performed that comparison and filtering for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call .Read() on your Reader object in order to increment through the rows of your result set.

```
rdr.Read();
```

//Note this will return false if there is no more record(s) to be read, so it is usually used inside and `if` statement or `while` loop

You could change your `if (Groupnametxt.Text.Trim() == (string)rdr["GroupName"])` to `if(rdr.Read())` because if there is at least 1 record in your table that has this `GroupName` value, it will return true.

```
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Group Name taken, please try another name", "Error in Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                membernumber1.ReadOnly = true;
                rdr.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                rdr.Close();
                sql = "INSERT INTO GroupNameNS VALUES ('" + Groupnametxt.Text.Trim() + "')";
                membernumber1.ReadOnly = false;
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I modified a couple other things too: don't forget to close your Reader object after using it. And [use `ExecuteNonQuery()` for an `INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Should use SQL Parameter for group name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional changes to ensure proper cleanup with the using keyword and adding Parameter for the groupname as a best practice.

```
using(OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection())
{
    db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" + fileName; 
    db.Open(); 

    string groupName = groupName.Text.Trim();   
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM GroupNameNS WHERE GroupName = '@groupname'"; 

    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, db))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupname", groupName);

        using(OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {       
            if (rdr.Read()) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Group Name taken, please try another name", "Error in Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
                membernumber1.ReadOnly = true; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                sql = "INSERT INTO GroupNameNS VALUES ('@groupname')"; 
                cmd.CommandText = sql;              
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                membernumber1.ReadOnly = false;         
            } 
        }
    }
}
```